# How to remove a class from an element when clicking on another class JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the class **type-product**, when I press the button **close-item-li**.

There are many such blocks. And the code that I wrote does not work. I do not understand what the problem is.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
<li class="type-product active-item-li">

  <button class="close-item-li">x</button>

</li>
```

```
$('.close-item-li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active-item-li');
})

$('.type-product').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active-item-li');
});
```

Comment: That is a very basic question which you can get the answer in all jQuery remove class tutorials. Kindly check [this tutorial](https://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-removeclass/).

Comment: @yogihosting 
Yes, this is a pretty simple question and I figured out what I will throw off from above. However, my code doesn't work and I don't know why. So I wrote this question.

Comment: Is that *all* your code?  Do you have a `<form>` tag?  Try changing your button to `<button type='button' ...` as otherwise it will POST your form.

Comment: My take is that your `.close-item-li` doesn't exist when you run this code, so the event is never caught. maybe you can bind it differently, via `$(document, '.close-item-li', function(){...})` which will catch all future instances of those buttons

Comment: Your code, *as provided*, can trivially be shown to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xdm5qjca/ - either there's something in the css so it is working but you think it's not or your `li`/`button` is added dynamically (as comment above) or your form is POSTing and refreshing the page so you *think* it's not working - *"does not work"* is not enough information.  Please convert your code to a snippet using the `[<>]` button to *demonstrate* it not working (and to confirm/demonstrate to yourself in the snippet rather than your own code which has other code) - see [mcve].

Comment: Also, your question says you need to remove `.type-product` but your code removes `active-item-li` - please clarify if you're simply removing the wrong class (from the problem, I would guess removing the active class).

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `.removeClass('active-item-li')` to `.removeClass('type-product')`.

```js
$('.close-item-li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('type-product');
})
```

It now seems to be working : (JS fiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/twspugkj/.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, I changed my answer and tried to add more comments.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work. What is the logic of your actions?

Comment: The logic is based on your question: "*I need to remove the class type-product*"

Comment: According to your question you want to remove the class "type-product" and if you look at the js fiddle via the devTools of your browser you will see that the class is removed.